# Show the post tags with a description in Single.php (not all tags, only the tags of that post with description)

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show single post tags with description in single.php.

I searched about this, the closest solution is below. But this code lists all tags of the blog with a description.

```
$tags = get_tags( array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );
if ($tags) {
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        if ($tag->description) {
            echo '<dt><a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tag->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tag->name.'</a></dt><dd>' . $tag->description . '</dd>';
        } 
    } 
}
```

I need to list only the post tags with description. (It should exclude the post tags without a description.)

**For example:**

We have **4500+** tags in database.

**200+** tags have description.

There are **7** tags on an example single post.

Only **4** of them are have a description.

**Result:**

I need to show only **4 tags in single.php**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code it will work in single.php

```
<?php

$tags = wp_get_post_tags(get_the_ID());
if ($tags) {
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        if ($tag->description) {
            echo '<dt><a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tag->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tag->name.'</a></dt><dd>' . $tag->description . '</dd>';
        } 
    } 
}

?>
```

Comment: This is not the code that I'm looking for. We need to modify the code that I share to filter "only the post tags"? I don't understand why you put there some specifications like term_id 4, cound_7 by the way. Is this a manuel method for only for a specific post or what? Thanks.

Comment: By passing the post ID in wp_get_post_tags function, you will get only tags related to that post, You can use this in single.php

Comment: you can use the above code it will work in single.php

Comment: Okay, It's great, So if you give upvote, I will be appreciated.  :)

Comment: It's worked for me too. Thank you for a suggestion.